# Фильтрация в LINQ запросах

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Есть LinQ запрос

```
var info = (from f in db.Flats
           join i in db.Indicators on f.IndicatorId equals i.Number
           join d in db.Datas on f.IndicatorId equals d.IndicatorId
           select new MainInfoViewModel
           {
               Address = f.Address,
               Indicator = i.Number,
               Date = d.Date,
               Value = d.Value
           }).ToList();
```

Как можно добавить условие для фильтрации списка, например для info с одинаковыми Indicator выводить то у которого больше Date?
https://prnt.sc/tyqkwv
Просмотр списка всех квартир с показаниями, актуальными на сегодня.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не первичный

Comment: Вам нужна группировка скорее всего. То есть, нужно вывести те записи, у которых одинаковый indicatorId и дата больше какой то даты? Сгруппируйте по  indicatorId, далее, используя инструкцию having выводите те, которые имеют больше одной записи. Ну а дата через where. Как это в Linq описать - дело второе Главное - сам sql написать.

Comment: Если задача звучит, как вывести адрес, Indicator, дату, значение так, что если в списке у каких то элементов дублируется Indicator, то для таких случаев будет применяться фильтрация по дате, то это сложное требование, я бы чистым запросом написал бы.

Comment: Я рекомендую автору не полениться и расписать вопрос получше. Дайте таблички (ну какие нибудь рисунки табличек), дайте четкое описание задачи.

Comment: Вы EF используете или что?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да!!

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak https://prnt.sc/tyqkwv

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak Нужно реализовать просмотр списка всех квартир с показаниями, актуальными на сегодня. То есть у Indicator вывести Value с наибольшей датой

Comment: В таком случае зачем вам джойны, пользуйтесь навигационными свойствами

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно пример? join я объединяю модели в одну, как теперь отсортировать это?

Comment: я бы попробовал поступить так, предварительно *отфильтровал* таблицу datas, что бы там были только последние значения `db.Datas.GroupBy(x=> new {x.IndicatorId}).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).First());` и в основном запросе уже использовал результат этого запроса

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak раньше я бы тоже написал чистый sql запрос и использовал его через EF, но потом модели могут измениться и этот запрос перестанет работать, я об этом конечно узнаю но позже, когда пользователь его выполнит. хотя может это я не умею *готовить* такие запросы

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov есть идеи?

Answer (score 0):

```
        info = info.GroupBy(i => i.Indicator)
                   .Select(i => i.Last())
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал добавить явную фильтрацию, что бы гарантировать результат, в текущей реализации это не так